# Dplyr join error. Why?

Tags: r, join, dplyr

Ok here's a quick reproducible example:

```
ppg2017 <- c(65,74,53,63)
team2017 <- c("Duke","UVA","UNC","Xavier")
year2017 <- c(2017,2017,2017,2017)

df.2017 <- data.frame(team2017,year2017,ppg2017)
names(df.2017) <- c("team", "year", "ppg")

ppg2016 <- c(68,61,82,71)
team2016 <- c("Duke","UVA","UNC","Xavier")
year2016 <- c(2016,2016,2016,2016)

df.2016 <- data.frame(team2016,year2016,ppg2016)
names(df.2016) <- c("team", "year", "ppg")

team <- c("Duke","UVA","UNC","Xavier","Duke","UVA","UNC","Xavier")
year <- c(2017,2017,2017,2017,2016,2016,2016,2016)

team.stats <- data.frame(team,year)

team.stats <- left_join(team.stats, df.2017, by = c("team", "year"))
team.stats <- left_join(team.stats, df.2016, by = c("team", "year"))

team.stats
```

How do I get it to not create a new column for ppg.y?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`coalesce`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.3/topics/coalesce)

```r
library(dplyr)

team.stats %>% 
  left_join(df.2017, by = c("team", "year")) %>% 
  left_join(df.2016, by = c("team", "year")) %>% 
  mutate(ppg = coalesce(ppg.x, ppg.y)) %>% 
  select(-ppg.x, -ppg.y)

#>     team year ppg
#> 1   Duke 2017  65
#> 2    UVA 2017  74
#> 3    UNC 2017  53
#> 4 Xavier 2017  63
#> 5   Duke 2016  68
#> 6    UVA 2016  61
#> 7    UNC 2016  82
#> 8 Xavier 2016  71
```

Created on 2018-03-12 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for (see comment on other solution) but I was able to build off of the idea and make it work. The way I did it was definitely not the most efficient, but it works. I'll worry about efficiency when I'm not on a deadline of this Thursday.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below.

```
team.stats <- data.frame(team,year)

team.stats_desired <- left_join(team.stats,rbind(df.2016,df.2017))
```

Comment: The issue is I'm looping through so I really have every individual stat for every year joining on. Does that make sense?

Comment: So you have operations between left_joins? Can you loop to bind all years and left join with team.stats?

Comment: Potentially. I'm trying to use the coalesce solution right now and think I may have found a possible fix. It's definitely not the most efficient way to do it, but it seems to be working. I'll work on efficiency when I'm not on a deadline of this Thursday.

Answer (score 0):

It seems `OP` is expecting to `fill` any missing rows in a year for a team after combining data for stats.

One solution could be found using `bind_rows` from `dplyr` and`complete` from `tidyr` package.

```
bind_rows(df.2017, df.2016) %>%
  complete(expand(.,team,year)) %>%
  arrange(desc(year)) %>% as.data.frame()

# team year ppg
# 1   Duke 2017  65
# 2    UNC 2017  53
# 3    UVA 2017  74
# 4 Xavier 2017  63
# 5   Duke 2016  68
# 6    UNC 2016  82
# 7    UVA 2016  61
# 8 Xavier 2016  71
```

Though there was no missing rows in `OP` sample data. But if we create a missing row in say `df.2016` then result will be:

```
df.2016 = df.2016[-1,]

bind_rows(df.2017, df.2016) %>%
  complete(expand(.,team,year),fill = list(ppg = 0)) %>%
  arrange(desc(year)) %>% as.data.frame()

# team year ppg
# 1   Duke 2017  65
# 2    UNC 2017  53
# 3    UVA 2017  74
# 4 Xavier 2017  63
# 5   Duke 2016   0     -- missing row
# 6    UNC 2016  82
# 7    UVA 2016  61
# 8 Xavier 2016  71
```